# Proper seperation of React component in container and presentational components for redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to seperate a component like mentioned in the title.

According to the redux tutorial for react it's a best practice to split components up.

Until now I have the following components:

### ReduxTestNetwork

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Edge, Network, Node} from '@lifeomic/react-vis-network';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import MyNetwork from "./MyNetwork";

...

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { nodes: state.nodes,edges: state.edges };
};
const VisNetwork = ({nodes,edges}) => (
    <MyNetwork nodes={nodes} edges={edges} options={options}/>
);
const ReduxTestNetwork = connect(mapStateToProps)(VisNetwork);
export default ReduxTestNetwork;
```

### MyNetwork

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Edge, Network, Node} from '@lifeomic/react-vis-network';
import connect from "react-redux/es/connect/connect";
import {addNode} from "../actions";

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        addNode: node => dispatch(addNode(node))
    };
};

class MyNetwork extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {nodes: props.nodes, edges: props.edges, options:props.options};
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('I just mounted')
        //this.onClick();
    }

    onClick(e){
        console.log(e)
        console.log(this)
       /* this.props.addNode({id:5,label:'Node 5'});

        this.setState(prevState => ({
            nodes: [...prevState.nodes, {id:5,label:'Node 5'}]
        }));*/
    }
    render() {
        const nodes = this.state.nodes.map(node => (
            <Node key={node.id} {...node}/>
        ));
        const edges = this.state.edges.map(edge => (
            <Edge key={edge.id} {...edge}/>
        ));
        return (
            <div id='network'>
                <Network options={this.state.options}   ref={(reduxTestNetwork) => {
                    window.reduxTestNetwork = reduxTestNetwork
                }} onSelectNode={this.onClick.bind(this)}>
                    {nodes}
                    {edges}
                </Network>
            </div>);
    }
}
const SVNetwork = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(MyNetwork);
export default SVNetwork;
```

I connected ReduxTestNetwork to the store to obtain the state as props and MyNetwork to be able to dispatch.

I read that presentational components should only be used to display elements and the container components should include the logic how and what to display. But I need in MyNetwork some logic also to interact with the Network component which uses a 3rd party library.

So my questions are:

1. Is my seperation correct?
2. Where should I put logic for (for example) calculating the size or color of displayed nodes?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things:

1. You don't need to use connect twice. Pass mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps at the same time, both on the container.
2. If you want to follow the path of purely presentational components, consider using a side effect library: refract, sagas, thunk... they have patterns to deal with your logic outside of the component.
3. If you prefer a more hand made approach, you could move every method you need to the container and pass to the component via props only the data and the function references to modify it.